# Convert text to number for customer satisfaction survey

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have customer satisfaction feedback like Good, bad, excellent etc, I would like to assign a numerical value like Excellent = 5, Good = 4, Neutral = 2, Unsatisfied = 0
Then sum the value by category

This query I need to start with "Select" only

Grouping by month
Excellent 400
Good 500

Answer (score 3):

use case when

```
select sum(case when satisfaction ='Excellent' then 5 
            when satisfaction ='Good' then 4
            when satisfaction ='Neutral' then 2
             when satisfaction ='Dissatisfied' then 0 end) as satisfaction_val
,category from table_name group by category
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a reference table for this purpose.  If you don't have one, you can put one together in the query itself:

```
select t.category, sum(v.satisfaction_val)
from t cross join
     (values ('Excellent', 5),
             ('Good', 4),
             ('Neutral', 2),
             ('Dissatisfied', 0)
    ) v(satisfaction, satisfaction_val)
    on t.satisfaction = v.satisfaction
group by t.category;
```

This is a better solution that just using a `case` expression in-line, because the values can be re-used.  For instance, if you want the total of number of positive responses, you might do:

```
select t.category, sum(v.satisfaction_val),
       sum(case when v.satisfaction_value > 3 then 1 else 0 end)
```